# Laravel How to delete session on the homepage

Tags: php, laravel, session

Im using javascript in **Homepage** to pass variable to next page (Im using controller to store variable in session) , now how can I empty the session if loaded the home page again?

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_getbids', function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'addItem',
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[country=_token]').val(),
        'country': $('input[name=country]').val() },
    success: function(data) {
   }, });
   $('#country').val('');});
```

**Controller**

```
  public function addItem(Request $request) {

   $request->session()->put('country', $request->country);

        return response ()->json ( $data );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an IndexController where you call the homepage function to call your home view.

```
public function homepage(Request $request){
    //check if session exists
    if($request->session()->has('country'){
        //forget session
        $request->session()->forget('country');
    }
}
```

With this code, session country will be forgotten every time you go to the homepage.

For your additional reference [Laravel Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session)

Comment: Ok the problem is when I get the session that I want and leave to the next page which display the session variable I got empty variable which means this will not save the session again??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
public function addItem(Request $request) {
    if($request->session()->has('country'){
         $request->session()->forget('country'); //if you want to clear specific one
         //$request->session()->flush  //if you want to flush all
    }

    $request->session()->put('country', $request->country);
    return response ()->json ( $data );
}
```

Comment: sometimes working and sometimes repeat the session variable!!